# UI-router stateParams cloning objects?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

I have this route:

```
{
  name : 'myPage',
  url  : '/myPage',
  views: {
    '@': {
      component: components.MyComponent.name
    }
  },
  params: {
    turtle: {y: 2}
  },
  resolve  : {
    turtle: function($stateParams) {
      window.turtle = $stateParams.turtle;
      window.daaa = $stateParams;
      return $stateParams.turtle;
    }
  }
}
```

I have this component binding def:

```
bindings: {
  turtle: '<'
}
```

and the constructor of MyComponent's controller:

```
class MyComponentController {
  let self = this;
  this.$onInit = function() {
    console.log("-----")
    console.log("window.turtle: " + JSON.stringify(window.turtle))
    console.log("self.turtle: " + JSON.stringify(self.turtle))
    console.log("window.turtle == self.turtle: " + (window.turtle == self.turtle))
    console.log("window.turtle == self.$stateParams.turtle: " + (window.turtle == self.$stateParams.turtle))
    console.log("window.daaa == self.$stateParams: " + (window.daaa == self.$stateParams))
    console.log("-----")
  }
}
```

It prints:

```
-----
window.turtle: {y:2}
self.turtle: {y:2}
window.turtle == self.turtle: true
window.turtle == self.$stateParams.turtle: false
window.daaa == self.$stateParams: false
-----
```

This is really strange to me..., made me think that once you're inside a state, UI-router makes a clone of $stateParams (so the $stateParams you see inside the resolves != $stateParams you see in the controller)... **and** it also makes a clone of each declared params (deep clone???).

I wasn't expecting that. Is it a bug? or a feature (maybe protection mechanism?). Who is the culpable here? UI-router? Or is it angular 1.5 component (with its isolated scope stuffs)?

Thanks in advance for helping me clarify this.

Comment: At least for window.daaa, UI-Router creates a new $stateParams every time it gets injected (It's a locals object, not an actual singleton service). No idea about window.turtle though

Comment: I don't mind with $stateParams being created every time it gets injected. But making a clone of all of the params? Too much work, isn't it? My code was written based on the assumption that you're getting the same instance (during resolve, and inside controller..., and subsequently in child states too)... until I ran into trouble (array manipulation), and did the checks above, and was quite surprised... and doubtful if that's a feature. Not documented in UI router page (or maybe vaguely worded)

Comment: BTW, You may want to put what version of UI-Router are you using in the question

Comment: angular-ui-router@1.0.0-beta.3 . Let me upgrade to rc1 and see what happens.

Comment: Whoa... confirmed.... it was a bug in beta 3. Now with rc1 I got what I was expecting.

Comment: Awesome - you may want to self-answer this then, so others can benefit :)

Comment: SORRY! False flag, was looking at other logs. It's still there in rc1. The problem.

Comment: Is it possible that UI-router is playing with Proxy? I mean, every instance of $stateParams hold a new Proxy of each params it carries. (?). Maybe for tracking purposes (?).

Comment: I tried digging a bit through the source - see https://github.com/ui-router/core/blob/48c5af6ec4dd3d34eb113524f9960431be255744/src/transition/transition.ts, which I *think* is where the $stateParams is created. I didn't see anything, but maybe... However, take a look at the comment https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/src/injectables.ts#L94, and see if it might help you...

Answer (score 1):

According to [ui-router source code](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/src/injectables.ts#L94) (was linked by Daniel [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41604008/ui-router-stateparams-cloning-objects#comment70411794_41604008)) `$stateParams` is deprecated and it's advised to use `$transition$` injectable instead (see ui-router docs on [$transition$](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/modules/injectables.html#_transition_))

Here's an example of using it in a resolve function:

```
$stateProvider.state('a-route', {
  // ...

  // define params for route
  params: {
    data: null
  },
  // set up data to resolve to params.data
  resolve: {
    data: ($transition$) => {
      return $transition$.params().data;
    }
  }
})
```

Please, see working example here:
http://jsbin.com/velekot/edit?js,output

NOTE: Docs also claim that one can inject the `$transition$` to a controller, but I couldn't make it work, so used a resolve fn.